# asp '[string: "SELECT * FROM Orders"]'

Tags: asp-classic

Hi all i am having some problems with a bit of code and i cant find the error

```
  sql = "select " * " from products where pic = 1 and product_code in ("

    count = ubound(codes)
    for each code  in codes
        if len(code) > 0 then
            sql = sql & "'" & code & "'"
            if i < count - 1 then sql = sql & ","
            i = i + 1
        end if
    next

    sql = sql & ")"

    set res = lo_con.execute(sql)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your sql string is wrong. But you didn't show us any error regarding your code. You need to be more specific in SO.

Comment: When you're debugging a query like that it's often a good idea to put in a `Response.Write sql` line before the line where it's executed, so you can see the actual query which is failing

Answer (score 3):

You are not including the star on your string. Try:

```
sql = "select * from products where pic = 1 and product_code in ("
```